# Check if the ion-input value is greater than 0 on "keyup"

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I need to Disable/Enable a button in Ionic based on the value of the ion-input. It should be triggered as soon as the user enters any value. (Targeted Event: keyup)

If the entered number is greater than 0, enable button, otherwise, it would be disabled.

Looking for options!

[Screen Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UL8t.png)

Here's input field will be Amount and targeted button will be Add Payment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `.html`

```
<input
   (input)="gotChar($event)"
   placeholder="Write your value..."
 ></input>

<button [disabled]="checker"></button>
```

Also you can make use of `(change)` like:

```
<input
   (change)="gotChange($event)"
   placeholder="Write your value..."
 ></input>
```

And in `.ts` file

```
class Home {
 checker:boolean = true;
 constructor(){}
 gotChar(eve) {
   this.checker = eve.target.value === '0' ? true : false ;
 }

 gotChange(eve) {
  console.log(eve.target.value);
  this.checker = eve.target.value === '0' ? true : false;
 }
}
```